# "Include Kotlin support" checkbox not in Android Studio 3.0 Canary 5

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, android-studio-3.0

I want to create a Kotlin project in Android Studio 3.0 Canary 5 (171.4141229) on my Windows 7 64-bit machine. However, when I start a new project, the first window of the wizard doesn't show the "Include Kotlin support" checkbox (neither does it show the "Include C++ support" checkbox).

It looks like this: [image]

What can I do to create a Kotlin project in Android Studio 3.0 Canary 5? All the tutorials (which use Canary 1) say that this checkbox should be there.

Comment: It seems that Canary 4 does have the "Include Kotlin support" checkbox though.

Comment: As mentioned on an answer that is currently deleted, you might have to resize that window, as those options appear below the horizontal rule under the "Package name" setting, and might be covered by some useless blank element that fills a good chunk of the lower portion.

Comment: update to the stable version. It will fix it

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you are satisfied that you have Kotlin support, either by switching to Android Studio 3 or installing the plugin, then do the following when you open Android Studio:

- Resize the window by dragging down.

I hope this will help you.

Comment: This was the solution. There was no scrollbar to indicate there was more content on that window, I just had to make it bigger so I could see the checkbox.

Comment: I was using Studio on a laptop with a small screen, couldn't enlarge the window. So I went to Settings/Appearance & Behavior/Appearance and used "override default fonts" to choose a smaller font size. And there it was... I love Java UIs.

Answer (score 5):

[image: Android studio 3.o]

Just resize the screen and extend it a bit. The kotlin support check box is hidden, just check out the image.

Answer (score 1):

You could try manually to install Kotlin plugin. Go to Preferences - Plugins and search for 'Kotlin'.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I've tried this as well and it doesn't work when I update the Kotlin plugin.

Comment: That's weird. With the plugin I was able to get that tool in my Studio 2.3 also. Can you check Kotlin version that you have installed. May be that is incompatible with Canary 5.